# Компонент Chart

Tags: .net, ado.net, c#

В наборе компонентов Visual Studio 2010 есть компонент Chart(диаграмма). У меня совсем не получается с ним работать -( Может скинет кто-нить ссылочку на подробное описание или объяснит тут? Буду очень благодарен.
Что Я хочу от этого компонента: Есть таблица. В таблице два столбца - дата и значение. Необходимо построить график изменения. После попытки забить в свойство "DataSource" компонента Chart представление таблицы, получаю вот такое:
[image]

хотя данные изменяются с совсем непохожей динамикой, кароч ничего не пашет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[По этой ссылке ты можешь найти примеры](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418) для твоего чарт-контрола, как для ASP.NET, так и для WinForms.

Надеюсь, поможет.

Answer (score 1):

График можно построить с помощью:

```
MyChart.Series.Points.AddXY(x value, y value);
```